# App and sometimes device crash after closing with Advanced Task Manager and reopening our app

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

We have an android Honeycomb app that shows a strange behavior after closing with the Advanced Task Manager app. The same error does not happen if the app is closed through Settings->Applications->Manage application

When using Advanced Task Manager to kill the app and then reopen the app, the app crashes and sometimes the entire tablet crashes and restarts. The stack trace shows that it starts our start up activity, which then calls the second activity. Activity2 does not launch for some reason and tries to launch again and again. A new intent is started for Activity2 each time it tries to launch it. This happens a few dozen or hundred times before the app, and sometimes the device, crashes. There is no loop or anything in the code that attempts to launch Activity 2 after a failed launch, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

The only difference I've noticed in LogCat between the two different methods of closing the app is the "paused" field:

Using settings:

```
11-30 17:24:57.840: INFO/WindowManager(4524): WIN DEATH: Window{41d67198 com.path/com.path.MainViewLayout paused=true}
```

Using Advanced Task Manager:

```
11-30 17:20:19.930: INFO/WindowManager(143): WIN DEATH: Window{40eac9f0 com.path/com.path.MainViewLayout paused=false}
```

I'm not sure what that field means, but I suspect that perhaps the app is trying to resume when using the Advanced Task Manager and starting new after the Settings method.

Does anyone know what might be going on here?